# Can't use pwntools lib

Tags: python, pwntools

I've been trying to solve some puzzles on CryptoHack and at some point it kinda requires me to use the pwntools lib. I'm not that knowledgable about python and adding libs.

So far i've tried to run the official .whl from the website but it spat out:

WARNING: The scripts [...] are installed in C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\Scripts which is not on PATH

I've then tried with the help of some older stackoverflow answers to solve the solution by adding something to the Path environment variables in advanced system settings but it didn't help.

ALso located the python libs folder and pasted a pwntools folder into it. Also didn't work.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Consider it your introductory exercice into hacking... ;)

Comment: Have you followed the installation instructions for pwntools? https://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/install.html